# SQL ISNULL but also need results if not exists

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query to export products from my database.  So far I can get it to pull the records if either a field in the 'extrafields' is null or has content but I am unable to figure out how to also include if no data exists in the 'extrafields' database  I'd be very grateful if anybody can offer any help, here's what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
 p.code as `SKU`,
 case when ISNULL (e.content) THEN p.name ELSE CONCAT(p.name,'-',e.content) END as `ItemTitle`,
 p.scLevel as `AvailableQuantity`,
 p.price1 as `RetailPrice`,
 '' as `Description`
 FROM  jss_products p
 INNER JOIN jss_extrafields_values e ON e.productID = p.productID
```

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead INNER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left join :

```
SELECT 
 p.code as `SKU`,
 case when ISNULL (e.content) THEN p.name ELSE CONCAT(p.name,'-',e.content) END as `ItemTitle`,
 p.scLevel as `AvailableQuantity`,
 p.price1 as `RetailPrice`,
 '' as `Description`
 FROM  jss_products p
 LEFT JOIN jss_extrafields_values e ON e.productID = p.productID
```

With this you will have null values as p.productID if they are not in the first table so you can filter them ( if you want ) with :

```
....where p.productid is null
```